# How to move objects and robot models using GUI?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to move objects and robot models using `move to` command in gazebo GUI? I have been trying to do it without success. Gazebo documentation also skims over it without going into details. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13445/how-to-move-objects-and-robot-models-using-gui?/) by [Siddhesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2618/siddhesh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The arrow buttons at the top allow you to drag models around the world from the gui.

Does that answer your question? What `move to` command are you referring to?

Although you're totally right... I can't find anything in the tutorials on basic gui operation. If it's not there somewhere it's definitely worth adding.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siddhesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2618/siddhesh/) on 2016-05-30**:
@Peter : I tried using arrow button and mouse to drag the model, but its only changing view angles. I get 'move to' option after right clicking on the model.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-05-31**:
Documentation about the toolbar move modes can be found here: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_b2&cat=#UpperToolbar . The "Move to" option on a model's context menu makes the view follow the robot, it's useful when the robot is moving around the world and you want to keep it within view ;)

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-05-31**:
@Siddhesh I think your using the wrong mouse button? First click the model, then click the arrows button. Then you should get arrows that can you can drag around.

**Comment by [Siddhesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2618/siddhesh/) on 2016-05-31**:
@Peter : Yes, I was using wrong mouse button. Thanks. @chapulina : Thank you. It was helpful.